# Incorporating openJDK and Java Web Start on a Jenkins executor

Tags: java, jenkins, java-web-start

I have a Windows Jenkins executor with OpenJDK installed. From my understanding, Java Web Start is no longer compatible. Is there a way around this or another solution to still be able to remotely connect to Jenkins master?

Comment: You cannot install OpenJDK, and furthermore any SW, on an _executor_. You can install SW on a _node_ (in the past _master_ or _slaves_, nowadays _master_ or _agents_). You cannot even define an executor on these. You can just specify the number of executors on each.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "_remotely connect to Jenkins master_". What's the use case?

Comment: Are you simply trying to connect an Windows agent (node) to the Controller (mastee)? Or are you looking for Java Web start replacement to use (not really necessary)?

Answer (score 0):

See [en:WP Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start):

> #### Deprecation
>
> With JDK9, several deployment technologies including applets and Java Web Start were deprecated by Oracle.
>
> In March 2018, Oracle announced it will not include Java Web Start in Java SE 11 (18.9 LTS) and later. Developers will need to transition to other deployment technologies.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Alternatives
>
> See also: [IcedTea § IcedTea-Web](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea#IcedTea-Web)
>
> The open-source IcedTea project provides an alternative JNLP implementation in IcedTea-Web. As of version 1.7.2, it also works on newer versions without official JWS support.
>
> To run Java Web Start-based application after the release of Java 11, the company Karakun AG has released the open source tool OpenWebStart, based on IcedTea-Web. The tool includes all the functionality of IcedTea-Web and adds extended features, such as native installers for Mac OS, Windows, and Linux. IcedTea-Web was created with support from RedHat and AdoptOpenJDK.
>
> Webswing is a specialized web server for running Swing based Java applications in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Java Webstart can be replaced by https://openwebstart.com/